# $\sqrt{\lambda}$ is an eigenvalues of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm not sure if it's true, but if it is, it can help me with another exercise:

Prove that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A^2$ such as $A\in M_{n\times n}^F$, ($F=\mathbb{C} $ or $F=\mathbb{R}$), then $\sqrt {\lambda}$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

I managed to prove to second direction but it's not really helpfull in that case.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider $A^2-\lambda I$. Then $A^2 - \lambda I=(A-\sqrt{\lambda}I)(A+\sqrt{\lambda}I)$.

So, if $v$ is an eigenvector in respect to the eigenvalue $\lambda$ then $(A^2-\lambda I)(v)=0$ so we have:

$$(A-\sqrt{\lambda}I)(v)=0 \quad \vee \quad (A+\sqrt{\lambda}I)(v)=0$$

So it's obvious that $v$ is an eigenvector for $\sqrt{\lambda}$ or $-\sqrt{\lambda}$, thesis.

Comment: But $ABv=0\nRightarrow (A=0 \vee Bv=0)$.
so why does: $(A-\sqrt{\lambda}I)(A+\sqrt{\lambda}I)v=0\Rightarrow (Av=0 \vee Bv=0)$ ?

Comment: Because $A$ commutes with itself and $A$ commutes with $\lambda I \quad \forall \lambda$